# Toggling View background

Tags: android, view

I have a View object on my Activity and I'd like to change the background resource of the view.  More specifically, I'd like to toggle it.

So I'll need some logic like this:

```
if (myView.getBackgroundResource() == R.drawable.first) {
  myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.second);
}
else {
  myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first);
}
```

The issue here being that there is no getBackgroundResource() method.

How can I obtain the resource a View is using for its background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the View remembers what resource it is using after it gets the Drawable from the resource.

Why not use an **instance variable** in your Activity, or **subclass the View** and add an instance variable to it?

Comment: I think I'm going to subclass the View.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just have a control variable that maintains the state? Lets you be flexible and allows you any number of drawables.

```
int[] backgrounds = {
    R.drawable.first,
    R.drawable.second,
    R.drawable.third
};

int currentBg;

void switch() {
    currentBg++;
    currentBg %= backgrounds.length;

    myView.setBackgroundResource(backgrounds[currentBg]);
}
```

Comment: Using a flag is going to be a problem as the number of these objects on the screen is dynamic. I'm already using the View's tag to hold some other piece of data.

Comment: In that case,  I'd create a drawable that has different images for the normal state and the checked state, and switch it like that. This is how checkboxes work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag to keep track of which was last set

```
private static final int FIRST_BG = 0;
private static final int SECOND_BG = 1;

private int mCurrentBg;

...

if (mCurrentBg == FIRST_BG) {
  myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.second);
  mCurrentBg = SECOND_BG;
}
else {
  myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first);
  mCurrentBg = FIRST_BG;
}
```

You would have to initialize `mCurrentBg` wherever the background is initially set though.

Comment: Using a flag is going to be a problem as the number of these objects on the screen is dynamic.  I'm already using the View's tag to hold some other piece of data.

Comment: I mean I suppose I could use a map and use the unique data I'm storing in each View's tag as a key...

Comment: If you want to use a map, you may as well just subclass your button (if all your views are the same type) and embed the flag there. But see the comment in my answer - a cleaner way might be to use a multi-state drawable properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of a resource via the `getResources().getIdentifier("filename", "drawable", "com.example.android.project");` function. As you can see you will need the filename, the type of resource (drawable, layout or whatever) and the package it is in.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated my logic fail.

I think you might be able to put the `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods to use here:

```
//set the background and tag initially
View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.view);
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first);
v.setTag(R.drawable.first);


if(v.getTag().equals(R.drawable.first)) {
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.second);
    v.setTag(R.drawable.second);
} else {
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first);
    v.setTag(R.drawable.first);
}
```

I have not tested this, but I think it should work, in theory. The downside is that you add a little overhead by having to manually tag it the first time, but after the initial tagging, you shouldn't have to worry about keeping track of flags.

Comment: I'm already using the tag to store some other data.  I think I'm going to subclass this view and add some variables.

Comment: Ah yeah, if you're already using it, better off to subclass it then. Good luck!